# Unable to edit VF pages in Eclipse

Tags: visualforce, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am getting below error while editing visual force pages in Eclipse(Neon) - Force.com IDE (eclipse45).

**org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput**

Comment: This appears to be an internal Eclipse error, so the first suggestion is probably to reinstall Eclipse and the Force.com IDE. Note that Salesforce has [officially announced the end of life](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/the-future-of-salesforce-ides.html) for the Force.com IDE - it's a good time to start evaluating alternatives.

Comment: Thanks For your response David. I have already tried uninstall and reinstall Eclipse and Force.com IDE but it couldn't solve this issue. Yes i am aware of end of life for Force.com IDE, i am working on alternatives (VS code + Salesforce extension pack) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, this issue is happening because there was no active connection with salesforce org. Tried to reconnect with salesforce org and its resolved the issue.